# RabbitMQ publishing with confirmation in transaction mode

Tags: rabbitmq

How can I get confirmation info about success publishing message to the queue when the channel is opened in transaction mode?

Comment: Please share ALL of your code via a git repository. I should be able to clone and compile it to see what you are trying. We don't even know what programming language you're using, how do you expect anyone to help?